# Using FFImageLoading:CachedImage in ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Been looking for an example online about this but can't seem to find one. Basically, i would like to use a FFImageLoading:CachedImage in a ListView with the source bound to a string with a url e.g. http://blah.com/image.jpg. This is what i have tried thus far but no image seems to be loaded.

```
<ListView IsVisible="true" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:viewmodel.TSViewModel.myArticles}">        
  <ListView.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>

          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="95" HeightRequest="95"
                    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                    Source = "{Binding ImageUrl}">
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontSize="Small"/>

          </StackLayout>

        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If there is something i'm doing wrong or i'm just not supposed to use it this way or there are better alternatives, please help me out. Also, i'm a beginner with xamarin forms and mvvm. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: So the images do load but only once I move away from the images page to another page then back to the images page. The images are being loaded in a content page within a tabbed page so maybe that has something to do with it. Any ideas on how to load them the first time the tabbed page is opened?

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
using TestApp.view;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using TestApp.database;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class HomePage : TabbedPage
    {
        public HomePage(TestAppDatabase db)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Children.Add(new Bakeries(db));
            Children.Add(new Bars());
            Children.Add(new Butcheries());
            Children.Add(new Restaurants());
            Children.Add(new Supermarkets());
            Children.Add(new Entertainment());
        }

    }
}
```

Bakeries.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestApp.model;
using TestApp.database;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp.view
{
    public partial class Bakeries : ContentPage
    {
        public Bakeries(TestApp db)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Eateries> bakeries = (List<Eateries>) db.GetBakeries();
            bakeriesList.ItemsSource = bakeries;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks ok. Is something printed in the Debug output? You can open it via `Debug > Windows > Output`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looked at the Debug output but nothing related to my problem seems to be printed. I tried with the Image view and the same result, nothing happens. Weird because it works when outside the listview, just not within - something i'm missing? I'm testing on a Windows Phone device 8.1 if that matters

Comment: Please share your XAML CS file to understand what's happening behind the scenes

Comment: I've added the xaml cs file for the first page which is the tabbed page. Like i previously stated, all the labels load correctly via binding but the image does not load unless i open a new page and then get back to the tabbed page. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

According to the API docs located here. https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API

You must add this line to your platform specific project (**AppDelegate.cs**, M**ainActivity.cs**, etc) before you use FFImageLoading:

```
CachedImageRenderer.Init();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already added that. It works fine when it's not in the listview, as soon as i put it in the listview nothing happens. I'm testing on a windows phone if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Nigel I just noticed that you have a  <ViewCell.View> tag. That isn't suppose to be there. Your stack layout should just be inside your view. At least according to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#Custom_Cells

Comment: I removed the <ViewCell.View> tag but still the same result, no image is being loaded. No idea what's going on at this point and i've been at this for hours.

Comment: @Nigel I suggest filing a bug on github then. We can help you there.

Comment: I have noticed similar problem but my image was coming from the app sandbox.  I tried using TypeConverter and it would error in UWP (apparently, UWP does not support TypeConverter as I found online).  So, I tried ValueConverter instead and it started to work.